# Velocity components in 3d space

Tags: angle

I am trying to calculate the x,y,z velocity components for a projectile being shot from a cannon. I have the magnitude (power) of the cannon & the zRotation, yRotation, xRotation of the cannon. The calculations for zRotation, yRotation are fine, but i cannot figure out how to account for the third angle. Thanks.

PS: These are my calculations for velocity with yawn & pitch

```
cannon->magnitude * cosf(degToRads(cannon->zRotation)) * sinf(degToRads(cannon->yRotation)),
        cannon->magnitude * sinf(degToRads(cannon->zRotation)),
        cannon->magnitude * cosf(degToRads(cannon->zRotation)) *cosf(degToRads(cannon->yRotation)));
```

What i have attempted for all 3 angles:

```
 cannon->magnitude * sinf(degToRads(zAngle)) * cosf(degToRads(xAngle)) * cosf(degToRads(yAngle)),
         cannon->magnitude * sinf(degToRads(zAngle)),
         cannon->magnitude * cosf(degToRads(zAngle)) * cosf(degToRads(xAngle))* sinf(abs(degToRads(yAngle))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a diagram indicating how the angles are oriented, and without knowing units, I can't be 100% confident that my answer will satisfy you.

That said, if you are given three angles, each associated with one of the three spatial directions, then you may be dealing with something like the "Direction Cosines" example given on [this webpage](https://www.intmath.com/vectors/7-vectors-in-3d-space.php). If this is the case, then your velocity vector will consist of these three components:

```
v_x=|v_initial|*cos(xAngle)
v_y=|v_initial|*cos(yAngle)
v_z=|v_initial|*cos(zAngle)
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!! It required a little more than this BUT this got the ball rolling for solving my issue. AMAZING +1